# Bulk Attach Or Insert Media To Post Without Opening Post Editor

Tags: posts, attachments, media, get-posts, bulk

How to create a custom panel inside wp admin dashboard where we can insert media to specified posts in bulk? Here is the illustration:

[image]

As shown on the image above, it list all available media on the left and provide the box where we can insert post id to attach the media to. And we can then bulk insert media to the specified posts by hit the attach buttons after we specified the post id for each listed media.

I had spent several days trying to figured out how to do it, had tried some plugins also media library editing, but still can not found the answer.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic per the [faq].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. Break the question down into more specific questions. Then research those questions and bring the unanswered questions to us.

For example, you might break this down into these specific questions.

How do I:

- Add a menu item to the Dashboard?
- Create an admin options page form?
- Submit a custom admin page form?
- Page a custom option page (page 1, 2, 3 ...)?
- Attach images to a post?
- Attach images to several posts?
- Attach several images to several posts?
- Get a list of uploaded media?
- Get a list of all posts?

Solve these more specific questions. Then combine them to solve the broader question. Some of these questions may be broken down into even more specific questions. Some of them have been answered many times.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it make my research easier. I actually just want to know if there is any plugin that can do a job like that, so I can implement it faster instead of build the tool from scratch, but it is an off topic question, so I changed my question.